# Mimicking Browser's Script Loading and Executing Behaviour in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have,

```
<script src="jquery.js" ></script>
```

Then any script after this will allows you to use jQuery($) variable. I need to mimic this behavior in javascript. What I need that add my script file,

```
<script src="myscript.js" ></script>
```

which will load jquery.js using javascript and any script after this tag will allow you to use jQuery($) variable. I have no control beside myscript.js file. So I need to make sure that jquery.js must be loaded before allowing the browser to run/execute/render next tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible. When loading scripts dynamically you need to use callbacks to ensure that those scripts are loaded and use them only inside those callbacks. You cannot have sequential `<script>` tags in which one of the scripts loads dynamically some other scripts such as jquery and have subsequent scripts use jQuery. Browsers load script tags sequentially and guarantee that they will be loaded in the same order, but once you start injecting dynamic scripts into the DOM the only way to ensure proper load is to use callbacks. Take a look at the [following article](http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting it up in two parts should work:

index.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

myscript.js:

```
document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>');
document.write('<script src="myprog.js"></script>');
```

myprog.js:

```
$(function(){
    alert('jquery ready');
});
```

Comment: As I said before I have only access to myprog.js.

Comment: If you only have access to one js file on that host, why don't you use that to do both document.writes, and the other js file (with your actual code) can be loaded from any other host (where you have access). Or isn't that an option?

Comment: Is you author any js library/framework ever? He has only access to his library.